# Printing VtkBmpWriter with QPrinter

Tags: qt, vtk, qprinter

I am able to save my render window as bitmap by doing:

```
vtkWindowToImageFilter *winToImg = vtkWindowToImageFilter::New();
winToImg->SetInput(mRenderWindow);
vtkBMPWriter *writer = vtkBMPWriter::New();
writer->SetInput(winToImg->GetOutput());
writer->SetFileName(aFilename.c_str());
writer->Write();
```

and I am able to use the QPrinter to print a ready bitmap image:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer);
dialog->setWindowTitle(tr("Print Document"));
if (dialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted) {
    return;
}
QImage testbild("C:\\test.bmp");
QPainter painter(&printer);
painter.drawImage(QPoint(0, 0), testbild);
painter.end();
```

But I do not know how to combine both and print the image from vtkbmpwriter. How can I extract the bmp image from vtkbmpwriter and pass it to the painter/printer?